# Could someone explain, how to use Pattern Matching MySQL function (REGEXP_LIKE) with match_type 'n'?

Tags: mysql

MySQL support Regular Expression and there is a 'match_type' as 'n'.

Which represents, 
The . character matches line terminators. The default is for . matching to stop at the end of a line.
[image]

**Could someone give some example how to use match type 'n'?**

Source:

- MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:oracle-sqldeveloper] if you search a MySQL solution? Also, what have you tried to resolve your problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The OP appears to be spamming tags for the sake of it, @NicoHaase . Perhaps they are trying to attract people who can't help them. For the OP's benefit: [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302)

Comment: @NicoHaase
Example with match-type: 'n' not available there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you are asking, but here's an example of how to use match_type n and the effect it has:

This produces no results, because `.` does not match a newline:

```
select * from (select 'abc\ndef' bar) foo
where regexp_like(bar,'abc.def');
```

This produces a result, by specifying match_type `n` to cause `.` to match a newline:

```
select * from (select 'abc\ndef' bar) foo
where regexp_like(bar,'abc.def','n');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WY-AmOkT)

> The default is for . matching to stop at the end of a line.

The documentation is poorly worded here; it seems to be assuming a `.*`, but the match_type applies to any `.`.

Comment: Thank your for your help. 
This tiny help motivate me to create a documentation on "How to use Regular Expression in MySQL".

https://medium.com/@artbindu/how-to-use-regex-in-mysql-5ab60a43a883

Thank You for your support. @ysth